# React onChange method not running from component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codemirror, react-codemirror

I am trying to override an onChange method in a component but the method is not running on any DOM events like onChange, onClick, onDblClick etc. Here are the codes for the part where the component is being rendered and the component. Here is the [onChange Documentation](https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2#events) for the package being used. Any help will be appreciated, thanks for taking out the time :)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import JsEditor from "../editor/dynamic/JsEditor";

const Contribute = () => {
 const [jsCode, setJsCode] = useState("");

  const onChange = () => {
    {
      console.log("Js change fired");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
          <JsEditor onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contribute;
```

**Component's Code**

```
import React from "react";
import { UnControlled as CodeMirror } from "react-codemirror2";

import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import 'codemirror/theme/material.css';
import 'codemirror/addon/lint/lint.css';
import 'codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css';



import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js';
import 'codemirror/addon/lint/javascript-lint';
import 'codemirror/addon/lint/lint.js';
import 'codemirror/addon/hint/javascript-hint';

import { JSHINT } from 'jshint';
window.JSHINT = JSHINT;

const JsEditor = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> JavaScript </h1>
      <CodeMirror
        value='//Write your JavaScript here :)'
        options={{
          gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
          mode: "javascript",
          theme: "material",
          lineNumbers: true,
          lineWrapping: true,
          lint: true, 
        }}
       
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default JsEditor;
```

Comment: What is the CodeMirror component?

Comment: Inside your JsEditor , you'd probably want to take out `props.onClick` and pass it onto your `CodeMirror`, just putting it on JsEditor without doing anything with it won't do anything.

Comment: You are passing onChange as a prop to JsEditor, but you are not using it in child, therefore onChange event is not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that is you are not passing the `onChange` prop to `CodeMirror`.
Check the code below, i'll mark the difference

```js
import React from "react";
import { UnControlled as CodeMirror } from "react-codemirror2";

import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import 'codemirror/theme/material.css';
import 'codemirror/addon/lint/lint.css';
import 'codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css';



import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js';
import 'codemirror/addon/lint/javascript-lint';
import 'codemirror/addon/lint/lint.js';
import 'codemirror/addon/hint/javascript-hint';

import { JSHINT } from 'jshint';
window.JSHINT = JSHINT;

const JsEditor = ({onChange}) => { // Receive the onChange passed to your component
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> JavaScript </h1>
      <CodeMirror
        value='//Write your JavaScript here :)'
        options={{
          gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
          mode: "javascript",
          theme: "material",
          lineNumbers: true,
          lineWrapping: true,
          lint: true, 
        }}
        onChange={onChange} // Pass the onChange prop to the library
       
      />
    </div>
  );
};


export default JsEditor;
```

Comment: So in the component we're basically getting the onChange as a prop from where we're rendering it and calling it inside the component's definition. That's how it's working, right?

Comment: That's exaclty what we are doing. If you don't pass the onChange to CodeMirror, it won't know what function should be called